# Html Video ogg not working

Tags: html, firefox, meteor, video

Hi guys can anyone explain why when I try use oog video of Firefox it does not work. Dont mind the handlebars I am using metoer. Which works fine with mp4, but with oog I get a error.

**Error**

```
HTTP “Content-Type” of “text/html” is not supported.
```

**Code**

```
<div class="video-cont">
    <video class="responsive-video center-align" id="video-player" >
    <source src={{video}} type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTTP server is not configured to handle `ogg` files correctly. When the browser requests `something.ogg` the server is responding with "Here is an HTML document" and then the content of `somthing.ogg`.

You need to configure your HTTP server to send the correct Content-Type HTTP response header.

Comment: Okay makes sense how to do this on meteor server I do not know but i will look into it.

Comment: Would you know how to do this in meteor by any chance